# Using Replace() to remove quotation marks from the start removes them all

Tags: c#, string, replace

I am trying to filter a *csv file* from quotation marks. This line strangely deletes all the quotation marks in the line:

before : `"NewClient"Name"`

```
foo = foo.Replace(foo.Substring(0, 1), "");
```

after  : `NewClientName`

Why is this happening? Shouldn't the `Replace()` method just delete the *first* occurence?

Comment: Why don't you simply use `line=line.Replace("\"","")`? If you just want to remove the leading quotation mark: `line=line.TrimStart('"');`

Comment: *"Shouldn't the replace method just delete the first occurence?"* No, [it replaces every occurence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Do you really have `"NewClient"Name"` as an input? Usually we *double* quotations in CSV: `"NewClient""Name"` -> `NewClient"Name` when `"NewClient"Name"` is a *syntax error*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually when working with CSV we *double* quotations:

```
a                 -> "a"
a"b               -> "a""b"
NewClient"Name    -> "NewClient""Name"
```

To cut such a quotation, i.e.

```
"NewClient""Name" -> NewClient"Name
```

when `"NewClient"Name"` being a *syntax error* you can try

```
private static string CutQuotation(string value) {
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    return value;
  else if (!value.Contains('"'))
    return value;

  if (value.Length == 1)
    throw new FormatException("Incorrect quotation format: string can't be of length 1.");
  else if (value[0] != '"')
    throw new FormatException("Incorrect quotation format: string must start with \".");
  else if (value[value.Length - 1] != '"')
    throw new FormatException("Incorrect quotation format: string must end with \".");

  StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(value.Length);

  for (int i = 1; i < value.Length - 1; ++i) 
    if (value[i] == '"') 
      if (i == value.Length - 2)
        throw new FormatException("Incorrect quotation format. Dangling \".");
      else if (value[++i] == '"') 
        builder.Append(value[i]);
      else
        throw new FormatException("Incorrect quotation format. Dangling \".");
    else
      builder.Append(value[i]);

  return builder.ToString();
}
```

As you can see, it's not just single `Replace()` routine.

Tests:

```
 // abc - no quotation
 Console.WriteLine(CutQuotation("abc")); 
 // abc - simple quotation cut
 Console.WriteLine(CutQuotation("\"abc\"")); 
 // "abc" - double quotation
 Console.WriteLine(CutQuotation("\"\"abc\"\"")); 
 // a"bc - quotation in the middle
 Console.WriteLine(CutQuotation("\"a\"\"bc\""));
```

Answer (score 1):

> Shouldn't the replace method just delete the first occurence?

You would think so, because you're using `Substring(0, 1)`:

```
string foo = "\"NewClient\"Name\"";
foo = foo.Replace(foo.Substring(0, 1), "");
```

But the substring is obtained before the call to `Replace()`. In other words, your `Substring()` and `Replace()` have no relation to each other whatsoever, so the code is equivalent to:

```
string foo = "\"NewClient\"Name\"";
foo  = foo.Replace("\"", "");
```

And [`String.Replace()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx) replaces all occurrences.

If you only want to replace the first instance, see [How do I replace the *first instance* of a string in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141045/how-do-i-replace-the-first-instance-of-a-string-in-net). If instead you only and always want to remove the first character, see [Fastest way to remove first char in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222125/fastest-way-to-remove-first-char-in-a-string). If you want to remove specific characters from the start of the string, see [C# TrimStart with string parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4335878/c-sharp-trimstart-with-string-parameter).

Answer (score 0):

No, Replace method replace all occurrencies of a char in the string (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx).

If you need to remove just fist/last char (if any) you can use Trim function:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4tt83f9(v=vs.110).aspx

in your case:

```
 result[i, 0] = result[i, 0].Trim('"')
```

Comment: `Trim('"')` will also remove the quotation mark at the end, which is not what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement works with this.

```
string strTest = "\"NewClient\"Name\"";
strTest = strTest.TrimStart('"');
```

which in your case it is

```
result[i, 0] = result[i, 0].TrimStart('"');
```

*Replace will remove and replace all matching char/string in the given instance.